# C# how to show image in picturebox

Tags: c#, image, picturebox, dicom

I'm trying to display dicom image using openDicom.net. What should i correct here?

```
openDicom.Image.PixelData obraz = new openDicom.Image.PixelData(file.DataSet);
// System.Drawing.Bitmap obrazek = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(element);
pictureBox1.Image = obraz;
pictureBox1.Show();
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you get any exceptions (if so, what do they say)?

Comment: Try with an Image object instead. Image.FromFile is very handy for that.

Comment: there's an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'openDicom.Image.PixelData' to 'System.Drawing.Image' "

Comment: Sounds exactly like what Pierra said is right.

Answer (score 1):

PixelData is not an image. PixelData is raw image information. In my experience, most DICOM files will be using jpeg2000 images. In order to convert them to something usable by a PictureBox, you'll need to convert it to an Image. For raw monochrome types, you can make it into a System.Drawing.Bitmap using the following conversion:

```
openDicom.Image.PixelData obraz = new openDicom.Image.PixelData(file.DataSet);

Bitmap img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(obraz.Columns, obraz.Rows, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

int resampleval = (int)Math.Pow(2, (obraz.BitsAllocated - obraz.BitsStored));
int pxCount = 0;
int temp = 0;

try
{
    unsafe
    {
        BitmapData bd = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, obraz.Columns, obraz.Rows), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, img.PixelFormat);

        for (int r = 0; r < bd.Height; r++)
        {
            byte* row = (byte*)bd.Scan0 + (r * bd.Stride);

            for (int c = 0; c < bd.Width; c++)
            {
                temp = PixelData16[pxCount] / resampleval;

                while (temp > 255)
                    temp = temp / resampleval;

                row[(c * 3)] = (byte)temp;
                row[(c * 3) + 1] = (byte)temp;
                row[(c * 3) + 2] = (byte)temp;

                pxCount++;
            }
        }

        img.UnlockBits(bd);
    }
}
catch
{
    img = new Bitmap(10, 10);
}

pictureBox1.Image = img;
pictureBox1.Show();
```

For other image types, you'll need to do a similar conversion with the appropriate values. This conversion is strictly for monochrome types, and only after they have been converted from jpeg2000 to jpeg. Performing this operation on a jpeg2000 image will give you exactly half of the image filled with static and the other half completely empty.

Comment: From where are you getting the PixelData16 class?